# Large files in wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data directory

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, windows, logs

I have discovered these files located in the **wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data** folder on my Windows 2008 server.

They are consuming about 22 GB on a 40 GB drive.

[image]

I am using a LMS called moodle, that may be kicking off the creation of them, I am not sure.

I am trying to determine:

1. what is creating these files?
2. can I delete them to reclaim drive space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1 - what is creating these files?

Those files are called binary logs. They contain a list of all completed SQL statements you have executed. Your mysqld process created them and autorotates at 1GB. Any restart of mysqld or issuing `FLUSH LOGS;` will close one binary log and open another

They got created because there is a line in my.ini that looks like this:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

Note the timestamps on each file

- `mysql-bin.000068` has `10/31/2012 2:13 PM`
- `mysql-bin.000069` has `11/1/2012 11:13 AM`
- `mysql-bin.000070` has `11/5/2012 11:51 AM`
- `mysql-bin.000071` has `11/9/2012 11:50 AM`
- `mysql-bin.000072` has `11/13/2012 11:13 AM`
- `mysql-bin.000073` has `11/16/2012 12:05 AM`

Here is what has been going

- On 10/31/2012 at 2:13 PM

  - `mysql-bin.000068` surpassed 1GB (1048576 KB)
  - `mysql-bin.000068` closed
  - `mysql-bin.000069` opened
- On 11/1/2012 at 11:13 AM

  - `mysql-bin.000069` closed due to mysql restart or `FLUSH LOGS;`
  - `mysql-bin.000070` opened
- On 11/5/2012 at 11:51 AM

  - `mysql-bin.000070` closed due to mysql restart or `FLUSH LOGS;`
  - `mysql-bin.000071` opened
- On 11/9/2012 at 11:50 AM

  - `mysql-bin.000071` surpassed 1GB (1048576 KB)
  - `mysql-bin.000071` closed
  - `mysql-bin.000072` opened
- On 11/13/2012 at 11:13 AM

  - `mysql-bin.000072` closed due to mysql restart or `FLUSH LOGS;`
  - `mysql-bin.000073` opened
- On 11/16/2012 at 12:05 AM

  - `mysql-bin.000073` surpassed 1GB (1048576 KB)
  - `mysql-bin.000073` closed
  - `mysql-bin.000074` opened

By the way, the reason it autorotates at 1GB? The default setting [**max-binlog-size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size) is 1GB.

> 2 - can I delete them to reclaim drive space?

As long as you do not have mysql replication installed, then yes.

First login to mysql and run

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

This will erase all binary logs and leave you with `mysql-bin.000001` with 107 bytes.

Next, if you comment it out like this

```
#log-bin=mysql-bin
```

and restart the mysqld process

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

The logs will no longer be written.

As a final step, you can then delete `mysql-bin.000001` from Windows Explorer.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: wow - thanks for the great insights.  I will and report back my results.

Comment: Awesome... is always good to learn from you Rolando

Comment: I replaced full ...\mysql\mysql5.5.24 But it's showing databases, not tables

Comment: @KarSho Each database directory contains the physical files making up the tables. DO NOT ERASE THEM !!!

Comment: i dont know abt physical files and all. Now I replaced fully. What to do?

Comment: @KarSho If you have a new question, please make a separate post. Try not to start a new conversation on this 17-month old post.

Comment: Further add `[mysqld]` and `disable_log_bin` as two seperate lines to the end of the my.ini file, otherwise it will continue to produce log files with a default filename.

Comment: As of today (2023) it is not enough to just comment out the `log-bin=mysql-bin` line. As then the logs will keep running with the default name. You would need to ensure that `skip-log-bin` is declared BELOW or AFTER the log-bin configuration option.

Comment: @user164863 Thank you for your observation. Please keep in mind that my answer was based on MySQL 5.5 and is still very usable today because of the shocking number of people and companies still using 5.5 (heartbreaking to me). So this answer would still help those running ancient MySQL versions.,

Answer (score 1):

Those are your database files. Do not to remove them. Mine are not so big (around 300 Mb), but I'm on the development enviroment and I'm using small databases.

In case you want to move them my advice is to use export/import tools on your current mysql admin application, it could be PhpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench or similar.

Make a search using `mysql database wamp` tags either [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=mysql%20database%20wamp) or in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20database%20wamp) and you will get lot of info on wamp and mysql database

**Edit**

According to your comment you need to do some cleanup in order to see what can be done to shrink the database. I've not used moodle, but a quick search returned this link as one of the results, maybe is what you are looking for:

[How to keep a moodle database clean and trim](http://www.pwsdb.com/pgm/?p=182)

Comment: I do not want to move anything, just reclaim a bit of disk space.  I have DB backups stored on another drive, are these snapshots or duplicates.  Can I delete the older ones? Thanks for insights.

Comment: Answer edited, check if now is ok