# Freeing up disk space in 'mysql\data'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to free up some space used by a `MySQL` instance, but I know pretty much nothing about `MySQL`.

I notice that in the `mysql\data` folder there are lots of `localhost-bin.0001**` files, as illustrated in this screen shot:

[image]

What are these? Can they be backed up/moved/deleted?

**Edit**

It seems from look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29748/large-files-in-wamp-bin-mysql-mysql5-5-24-data-directory?rq=1) that these files are log files and can be deleted.

The post mentions:

```
As long as you do not have mysql replication installed, then [you can delete the files].
```

How do I check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should run the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) ReplicationUserCount
FROM mysql.user WHERE Repl_slave_priv = 'Y';
```

If `ReplicationUserCount` > 0, then the DB Server can be used as a Master. Ask your sysadmins or DBAs if there are any active or dormant Slaves.

If `ReplicationUserCount` = 0, then the DB Server is standalone. You could then just delete all or some of your binlogs using these methods:

## METHOD #1

```
RESET MASTER;
```

When you run this, all binlogs are erased and `localhost-bin.000001` is created.

**ALTERNATIVE**: Shutdown mysql, delete `localhost-bin.*`, and startup mysql.

## METHOD #2

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'localhost-bin.000190';
```

When you run this, all binlogs before `localhost-bin.000190` are erased.

## METHOD #3

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW());
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2014-03-26 15:30:00';
```

When you run this these, this is what they do

- all binlogs before today are erased
- all binlogs before midnight 3 days ago are erased
- all binlogs before 3:30PM on Mar 26, 2014 are erased

## CAVEAT #1

If methods 2 or 3 fail, this indicates that there may be a problem with the file `localhost-bin.index`. It keeps a text file with the list of the bin logs. If the file is out of sync, use `METHOD #1`. It will recreate `localhost-bin.index`.

## CAVEAT #2

Do not erase the binlogs from the Linux command line with `rm` or from the Windows Explorer. Doing so will throw the `localhost-bin.index` out of sync. If you do that, just do METHOD #1 and mysqld will clean it all up.

## CAVEAT #3

If you set `expire_logs_days = 7` in your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini`), it will automatically run this

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

on every log rotation or mysql restart.

## EPILOGUE

Since you are interest in recovering space, choose one of the three methods. You can place `expire_logs_days = 7` in your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini`) if you want. If you do not want it to grow past2 or 3 binlogs, then set this in your config file:

```
[mysqld]
expire_logs_days=1
```

and run

```
SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days=1;
```

to limit the number of binlogs to a single day.

Keep in mind that setting [**expire_logs_days**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) does not work if `localhost-bin.index` is out of sync.

Answer (score 3):

The `show master status;` command will show current binary log file from where database is reading the transactions.

To delete old binary log file automatically set `expire_logs_days=number of days`. By setting this variable it will automatically delete all binlog files before number of days set in `expire_logs_days`.

The number of days for automatic binary log file removal 7 to 10 days value is good, even if replication is setup.

eg. add following variable in my.cnf file.

```
expire_logs_days = 7
```

Or

```
set global expire_logs_days = 7;
```