# MySQL : 30GB of binlogs in 6 Hours

Tags: mysql, binlog, tungsten-replicator, multi-master

I have a mysql master/master setup with tungsten replicator. My server is reaching out of space, occupied around 30G in 6 hours. I'm not sure how to handle this. Would be great if some one can help me out of this.

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to erase all binary logs older than 30 minutes, do this

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```

If you want to erase all binary logs except the last one, do this

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
```

If you want to erase all binary logs before midnight, do this

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
```

If you want to erase all binary logs before midnight 3 days ago, do this

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

I have discussed deleting binary logs like this before

- `Apr 26, 2013` ; [Is it safe to delete mysql-bin files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/is-it-safe-to-delete-mysql-bin-files/41054#41054)
- `May 28, 2014` : [Freeing up disk space in 'mysql\data'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66028/freeing-up-disk-space-in-mysql-data/66069#66069)

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 3):

Rotate logs:

```
  mysql> FLUSH LOGS;
```

[Re]move the old binary logs, all except the latest it's safe to remove.

Comment: Can i purge logs which are 30 minutes older? What will be the exact command?

Comment: Only if MySQL isn't writing to it.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not understand

Comment: The "binlog.index" file also will need to be adjusted!