# MySQL dump with low disk space

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, disk-space

I have an asterisk PBX that has call recordings stored in a SQL database table.

This table has 9199 rows and is consuming 21GB on my server. I want to dump the data in this table to restore space on the server. I also only have 2GB of space left on my server. So could someone please help me with the following:

1. Is there an issue if I start to flush the table with only 2GB of space on my disk?
2. What would be the best command to use to flush this table?

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB? If InnoDB - what's `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: You can redirect mysqldump output to gzip, that might put it well under 2GB depending on the data.

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the 21GB table.

Comment: What is the name of the biggest file?

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the logs if you don't need them.

there is something freak in 9199 rows and consuming 21GB

see [Freeing up disk space in 'mysql\data'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66028/freeing-up-disk-space-in-mysql-data)